# How can i draw a rectangle around the pictureBox1 borders?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the pictureBox1 paint event i tried to draw a rectangle around the Image in the pictureBox1:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {           
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5), new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Image.Width,
                    pictureBox1.Image.Height));           
        }
```

But what i get is this:

[image: Rectangle around image]

And i also tried to draw a rectangle aorund the pictureBox1 it self:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, 0, 0
                                     , pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }
```

But in this case i'm getting a thick green line only on the left and the top the right and bottom without green.

[image: Rectangle around pictureBox]

The pictureBox1 in the desinger it's property SizeMode is set to StretchImage
How can i draw the rectangles in both cases ?

And how the property of the top line i called ? It's not Height maybe top ? If i want to find and draw only on the top of the pictureBox how does it called ?

Comment: Use the second code example but decrease the width and height location of the rectangle with -1 or less. `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, 0, 0
                                     , pictureBox1.Width - 1, pictureBox1.Height - 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw inside picturebox it is easy:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float penWidth = 5F;
    Pen myPen = new Pen (Brushes.Red, (int)penWidth);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, penWidth / 2F, penWidth / 2F, 
                             (float)pictureBox1.Width - 2F * penWidth, 
                             (float)pictureBox1.Height - 2F * penWidth);

    myPen.Dispose();
}
```

To draw outside picturebox you need to know which control is underneath it. eg if it is your *form* then use *form paint*:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int lineWidth = 5;
    Brush  myBrush = new SolidBrush (Color.Green);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, pictureBox1.Location.X - lineWidth, 
          pictureBox1.Location.Y - lineWidth, pictureBox1.Width + 2 * lineWidth, 
          pictureBox1.Height + 2 * lineWidth);

    myBrush.Dispose();
}
```

I am using *FillRectangle* because the part that is under *picturebox* is not visible and it is easier to control the width.